# Loading some packages with Rstudio server does not work, while it works with R server

Tags: r, linux, rstudio-server, terra

I am using `Rstudio server` on a remote server and I have some packages already installed.

When I try to load libraries like `raster` or `terra` using `Rstudio server`, I get error:

```
> library(terra)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘terra’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/pearless/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/terra/libs/terra.so':
  libproj.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

> library(raster)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/pearless/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/terra/libs/terra.so':
  libproj.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please, note that loading other packages using `Rstudio server` such as `tidyverse` works just fine:

```
> library(tidyverse)

── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
✓ ggplot2 3.3.5     ✓ purrr   0.3.4
✓ tibble  3.1.6     ✓ forcats 0.5.1
✓ readr   2.0.2     
── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

When I use `R` console in the server without using `Rstudio server`, the `raster` and `terra` packages can be loaded without any problem:

```
$ R

R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(terra)
terra version 1.4.11

> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
```

How can I solve this problem, so that I can also load these packages in `Rstudio server`?

**UPDATE** based on @user2554330's comment:

1. `.libPaths()` gives exactly the same result in both.
2. `Sys.getenv("PATH")`  and `Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` give different results in `R` and `Rstudio` server consoles - `Rstudio server` does not seem to be seeing most of the path variables. I ran `pth = Sys.getenv("PATH")` and `ld_pth = Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` in `R` in the server, and copied the results and pasted them into `Sys.setenv(PATH = "result_of_pth")` and `Sys.setenv(PATH = "result_of_ld_pth")` in the `Rstudio server` respectively. After doing this, I still get the same error when I load the libraries `raster` and `terra`.
3. Yes, both are running with the same username.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities.  Are both versions using the same libraries?  (Run `.libPaths()` in both to check.)  Do both see the same environment variables, including `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?  Are both running with the same username?

Comment: @user2554330 please see the update and kindly let me know what you think :)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling those packages as root?

Comment: @runr would you please clarify what you mean by  installing as "root"?

Comment: Through, e.g., ``sudo R``, from there running ``install.package(..)`` again for those packages that cause issues

Comment: @runr it seems like I am not allowed to run `sudo R` as it is a remote server and I have no permission to run this command. Why do you think it would help? :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything.  You might find some useful information if you run `maketools::package_sysdeps("terra")` or `maketools::package_sysdeps("raster")`.

Answer (score 6):

Per [robert-hijmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635245/robert-hijmans) reply, I solved this by adding the following:

```
apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    libudunits2-dev \
    libgdal-dev \
    libgeos-dev \
    libproj-dev \
    libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Easier to use command: `apt install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be that `terra` does not work, and because `raster` depends on it, that package cannot load either.

From a Google search on the error message  `libproj.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I see [this](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1377) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875754/r-load-error-libproj-so-13-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di) discussion, and perhaps more relevant pages.

These discuss the `sf` package but that package uses the same system dependencies as `terra`, so this should apply to `terra` as well.